# Prevent child event from firing

Tags: javascript

I have a slider that I am currently making. I am making slow progress, but I am making progress nonetheless!
Currently I have this:

http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/mEKyGG?editors=1011#0

There are 2 things you can do with this control, the first thing is you can drag left or right. The second thing you can do is click a "point" and it will scroll to the center.
The problem I have is that if I start dragging from a point, when I let go it will invoke the **moveToCenter** method.

I have tried to prevent this by adding

```
// Stop from accessing any child events
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

to the end of the **dragEventHandler**, but this did not work.
I also have 2 boolean values **options.drag** and **options.start**. I though I might be able to use them somehow (if the drag has started and is enabled then don't perform the **moveToCenter** but this didn't work either.

Do anyone have any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: Try `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` instead of `e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: `stopPropogation` prevents the event from bubbling up and firing events on the parent, not the other way around. `preventDefault` stops the default behavior of the element. (IE: a submit button from refreshing the page).

Also, please add the code to your question instead of linking to codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help. You can register your events in bubbling or capturing mode, using addEventListener method. It defines orders of processing your events - child -> parent (bubbling), or vice versa (capturing).

> http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

So, if you use addEventListener(event, handler, **true**), it will use capturing event mode.

Codepen:

> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZKdqV?editors=1011

```
divs.forEach(function (div) {
      div.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log('parent');
      }, true);  
  });
```

Be aware of browser support (IE9+). All modern browsers - yes, of course.

> http://caniuse.com/#search=addeventlistener

**Update**

So it turned out to be easier than first approach. (no need for capturing)
Check out codepen:

> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QExjzV?editors=1010

Changes from your sample:
At the beginning of *moveToCenter: function(e, options, animate)* function

```
if (options.started) {
  return;
}
```

In *if (['mouseup', 'mouseleave'].indexOf(e.type) > -1)*:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  options.started = false;
} , 100);
```

instead of

```
options.started = false;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: seems to do something really weird if I change the even listeners to capturing. When I try to scroll it stops abruptly. http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/JKkdOa?editors=1011#0

Comment: @r3plica yeah, doesn't look like it's exactly what you wanted :) I will try to play around and let you know if find a solution

Comment: Why are you quoting the urls?

Comment: @Simon hm.. maybe I should stop doing this

Comment: Your update works fine. just for my own information; why do you use a timeout to set `options.started = false;`

Comment: @r3plica I debugged the code, and it turned out, that moveToCenter is being called immediately after mouseup. So, to prevent moving to center, I use this workaround.